# ST_IsValidReason get all points 'Self-intersection'

Tags: postgis

Check this geometry, please:

> ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON Z (((228696.8 338223.3 0,228563.8 338278.5 0,228579.6 338194.2 0,228678.5 338298.6 0,228573 338078.6 0,228512.3 338355.7 0,228696.8 338223.3 0)))') as geom

There's 4 'Self-intersection' points, but the location(ST_IsValidDetail(geom)) select only one

> SELECT location(ST_IsValidDetail(geom)) as geom, reason(ST_IsValidDetail(geom))

How can I get all points?

---

Something like: [ST_DumpInValidReason](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/51)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that in no way at the moment. IsValidDetail gives additional information about validity and knowing one error location is usually enough.

Your wish is understandable from the point of view of someone who tries to correct the geometries by editing them manually but obviously the author of the IsValidDetail has had other priorities.

Here is the source code from a similar ST_IsValidDetail function of H2 Spatial https://github.com/orbisgis/h2gis/blob/v1.2.4/h2spatial-ext/src/main/java/org/h2gis/h2spatialext/function/spatial/properties/ST_IsValidDetail.java and it shows that the result is only one point

```
details[2] = GF.createPoint(error.getCoordinate());
```

Interestingly PostGIS and OpenJUMP report different locations for the error even OpenJUMP is using the JTS function and PostGIS is using GEOS which is ported from JTS.

PostGIS:

```
POINT Z (228643.440954767 338261.591260644 0)
```

OpenJUMP:

```
POINT ( 228632.46264019504 338250.00242301676)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your task is solved in two steps:

step 1)

`create table exper_table as
SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(ST_MakeValid
(ST_GeomFromText ('MULTIPOLYGON Z(((
228696.8 338223.3 0,
228563.8 338278.5 0,
228579.6 338194.2 0,
228678.5 338298.6 0,
228573 338078.6 0,
228512.3 338355.7 0,
228696.8 338223.3 0)))')
))).geom`

`ALTER TABLE exper_table ADD COLUMN id serial not null;`

and step 2)

First Shot:

`DELETE FROM exper_table
WHERE id IN (SELECT min(id) as id_point FROM exper_table group by geom);`

Second Shot:

`DELETE FROM exper_table
WHERE id IN (SELECT min(id) as id_point FROM exper_table group by geom);`

SEE THE RESULT :-),

`SELECT ST_AsText(geom) from exper_table;`

Still to understand how many times to shoot, :-) ... either cartridges can end, or "right points",

(Most likely, this may depend on how many times the same point coincides with the corresponding incorrect point ...)

You were the bad guy gangster Joe,

try not to use the weapon as intended, and you will become like me......

Success to you

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Cyril, but this is an example for lots of them...
It result for some but not for all

[image]